# codeigniter .htaccess not working in iis 7.5

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, iis

Hi i have a site in codeigniter working perfect on wamp in loacl server but when i uploaded the files on my online server which is iis 7.5 there homepage works fine but when i open the other page like `mysite.com/products` it gives error but when i put the url like this `mysite.com/index.php/products` then it works fine. before uploading the files i removed some folders in server some config folders for iis. how can i create the web.config file. is there any hierarchy for the config folders ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the URL Rewrite tool in the IIS Manager to import your .htaccess file that removes index.php in the url. This will create an IIS web.config file. Your .htaccess should look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yourappfolder

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#‘system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And your web.config file will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^system.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```